# Simple html page not delivered by static express

Tags: javascript, express

Banging my head... not a pro in Javascript but usually experienced enough to get things running. Not this time and I don't understand why:

Node: 8.15.1
Npm: 6.13.7

**UPDATE**: jslib here is just an example name (in reality it's a commercial 3rd party lib) and not actually jslib.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jslib": "file:../path_to_local_lib/lib/es-modules"
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port)
});
```

And in my /public folder I have one index.html and one basegraph.js:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/lib/lib.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="graphComponent"></div>

<script type="module" crossorigin="anonymous" src="basegraph.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and basegraph.js:

```
import { GraphComponent } from 'jslib'

const graphComponent = new GraphComponent('#graphComponent');
```

Now `npm install` runs without issues, `npm start` starts up server on port 8000 but opening it in my browser results in:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/node_modules/lib/lib.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So I assume I have an issue with the express static delivery? But I don't understand it.

And 2nd:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jslib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

So what I am doing wrong here? :-(

Comment: why you are using the manual file rather than https://www.npmjs.com/package/jslib npm jslib

Comment: because this 3rd party library has a commercial license and is only available to me this way - I updated my question to make this clear.